# OpenCv SimpleBlobDetector does not find all blobs. C++ , VS2015

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2015

I have a simple task for OpenCV SimpleBlobDetector

```
cv::SimpleBlobDetector::Params params;
cv::Ptr<cv::SimpleBlobDetector> detector = cv::SimpleBlobDetector::create(params);
std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> keypoints;
detector->detect(crop, keypoints);
drawKeypoints(crop, keypoints, crop, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 255), cv::DrawMatchesFlags::DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS);
cv::imshow("crop", crop);
cv::waitKey(0);
```

It is not detecting half of the blobs in my image.
Please see picture below,

I tried adding parameters and varying them, at no point has it ever detected every single blob.
Blob detection is a simple and straightforward algorithm that should be completely refined in every image processing API. Is this not the case with OpenCV?

```
//params.minThreshold = 0;
//params.maxThreshold = 255;
//params.filterByArea = true;
//params.minArea = 1000;
//params.maxArea = 5000;
//params.filterByCircularity = true;
//params.minCircularity = 0.4;
//params.filterByConvexity = true;
//params.minConvexity = 0.87;
//params.filterByInertia = true;
//params.minInertiaRatio = 0.71;
```

[image: blob detection test image HERE]

I'm using either OpenCV 3.3 or 3.2, I can't seem to find the version number in the sources

Comment: It seems like part of the blobs get filtered by the algorithm due to some parameters. Try disabling all filtering (e.g. `params.filterByCircularity`, `params.filterByConvexity`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im not sure if this is properly going to answer my question, but I had to write my own blob detection, it appears that OpenCV SimpleBlobDetector is not so simple.